# PHP checkbox updates database but drop drop menu doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script on checkboxes that works and updates my database accordingly.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$host = $row['host'];
$environment = $row['environment'];

echo "<tr><td>" . $host . "</td><td>" . $environment . "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='" . $host . "'/></td></tr>";
}

 echo "</tbody></table><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>";

if(gettype($_POST['id'])=="array"){
foreach($_POST['id'] as $val){
 $id_c = $val;
 $query1 = "UPDATE hosts SET reboot = 'Yes' where host='".$id_c."'";
 $result= mysql_query($query1);
 if($result === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
 }
 echo "Reboot updated for Host " .$id_c. " is updated. <br>
```

but when I replace it with checkboxes it doesn't work. The checkbox script is below.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$host = $row['host'];
$environment = $row['environment'];

echo "<tr><td>" . $host . "</td>
      <td><select name='id[".$host."]'><option value='Null'>Select any</option>
                              <option value='DEV/QA/TEST'>DEV/QA/TEST</option>
                              <option value='PROD/STAGE'>PROD/STAGE</option>
                              </select></td>
                              <td>" . $environment . "</td></tr>"; }


echo "</tbody></table><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>";

if (gettype($_POST['id'])=="array") {

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $host => $val){

            $id_c = $val;
if ($val != 'Null') {
            $query1 = "UPDATE hosts SET environment = '$val' where host='$host'";

            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

            if($result1 === false) {

            die(mysql_error());
         }

     echo "Environment for Host " .$host. " is updated. <br>";

}}}
```

Working updated script is here now.

Comment: curly quotes `‘id[]’` will put a damper on your day

Comment: same for `$host . “’>` and `</tr>”;` - question is off-topic for a few reasons. Don't use Word to code, use a code "editor".

Comment: whoever's suggestive edit to add the mysql tag; it isn't mysql related, it's a php issue/quotes/html

Comment: The funny quotes could have come in here my mistake. I have proper quotes in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lower script, you still use `$_POST['id']`, but your select field has the name `select` and the `id` field is a hidden field. So the values from the select box will never be used.

Kill <strike>`<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='" . $host . "'>`</strike> and
`<select name='select'>` will be `<select name='id[]'>`.

And, please, correct those quotes and try to have an eye on sql injection, as your script is vulnerable to that.

Comment: Can you edit and show me as to which filed I should choose to update the database? Much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the script and it still doesn't update the database. I have edited my original post.

Comment: The `UPDATE` statements in your solutions do fundamentally differ. I thought you wanted to achieve the same functionality but only replace the checkboxes by radio buttons? The upper query looks correct to me but that depends on context.

Comment: I have edited my original post once again. With the new changes, right now, the last host is getting a value of 0. How do I keep track hosts that were selected and the value it holds to update the database?

Comment: The value of 0 is returned if no selection is made. To ignore it, you should insert a `if ($val=='0') continue;` right at the start of your loop.

Comment: Okay, but how do I keep track of the hosts and value selected?

Comment: I have edited my drop down menu script. Can you please check? It is still now working.

Comment: You did part of the change I inteded to propose while I was typing =) `id[<?php echo $host; ?>]` should be `id[".$host."]`...

Comment: Awesome! It works. One small problem. Right now, If some users do not select anything for a host, the environment column gets a 0 and the selected ones get appropriate fields populated, but the user where to try again to select the previously unselected ones, the earlier selected ones get 0 and the recently selected one get the value. How can I not update the database if a value already exists in it?

Comment: Congratulation! I would use an inline if which checks whether the `$environment` holds the option value and if so, outputs a `selected` attribute. Like:`<option value='DEV/QA/TEST'".($environment=='DEV/QA/TEST' ? ' selected' : '').">DEV/QA/TEST</option>`. The same for PROD/STAGE

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. There is one issue left, please get yourself informed about sql injection attacks, because this is a security risk in your code. There is a lot of stuff about it here on SO and out there on the web.

Comment: How can I get the page to refresh once the user clicks on submit? The refresh has to be once the database has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

This code will set the value to `$host` only if the user has checked the box:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='" . $host . "'/>
```

Whereas this code will set the value `$host` regardless of what the user does.

```
<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='" . $host . "'>
```

Try removing the `hidden` input and setting the `select` `name` to `id[]` instead.

Comment: I changed my original post and it still doesn't work. Mainly how do I get the right host and update it?

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);` to see if the results are expected. Then try to run an expected SQL query in phpMyAdmin